# What is the Best Way to Scale an external (non EKS) EC2 Auto Scaling Group from Inside a Kubernetes Cluster Based on Prometheus Metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, autoscaling

I am currently autoscaling an HPA via internal Prometheus metrics which then filters down to scale the cluster via the AWS Cluster Autoscaler. That HPA is tied to an external service run on bare EC2 instances. I would like to use the same metrics that I use to scale that HPA to also scale the ASG behind that service that is external to the Kubernetes cluster.

What is the best way to do this? It is preferable that the external EC2 cluster does not have network access to the EKS cluster.

I was thinking about just writing a small service that does it via the AWS API based on polling Prometheus intermittently but I figured that there must be a better way.